# Has the Israeli left wing also endorsed the calls for Hamas to be killed to the last member?

Tags: armed-conflict, parties, israel

According to media [reports](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-67082351), the center-right part of the Israeli political spectrum has declared that the [ideal] goal of the military operation is to kill Hamas to the last member. Netanyahu and Gantz have said nearly the same thing in that regard.

> Israel's Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu said every Hamas member was "a dead man" after the first meeting of his country's emergency government. [...]
>
> Mr Gantz told Israeli citizens that the newly-formed government was "united" and ready to "wipe this thing called Hamas off the face of the Earth".

Have such calls also been endorsed by the left wing parties in Israel?